# Interacting with multiple inheritants of an S4 class

Tags: r, r-s4

I'm fairly new to Object Oriented Programming in R, and I'm trying to understand inheritance. I have a problem wherein I need to be able to see all class objects inheriting from the parent class object, and I'm not sure how to do it.

I can demonstrate my problem using a common example from online resources:

```
setClass("Person",
  slots = list(name = "character", age = "numeric"))
setClass("Employee",
  slots = list(boss = "Person"),
  contains = "Person")

## Create boss Alice
alice <- new("Person", name = "Alice", age = 40)

## Create Alice's subordinates
john <- new("Employee", name = "John", age = 20, boss = alice)
bob <- new("Employee", name = "John", age = 26, boss = alice)
jane <- new("Employee", name = "Jane", age = 22, boss = alice)
```

I've now created three employees, all of whom have the same boss: Alice. However, when I query Alice's class object, I cannot see who her employees are. I know that this is not how the class object is intended to work, but given that for my purposes I need to be able to see who all of Alice's employees are, what's the best solution I would use to go about doing this?

And additionally, I would like to be able to loop through each of Alice's subordinates, then extract and interact with each of their Employee class objects.

Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```
myFunction(funClassObj) {
  print(paste("Subordinate name: ", funClassObj@name))
  print(paste("Subordinate age: ", funClassObj@age))
}

for(subClassObj in alice@subordinates) {
  myFunction(subClassObj)
}
```

I've been unable to pull this off, and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check this really basic solution of mine. I think you can refine Employee or Person with SetClassUnion. You could tweak it to work with the employee instead of the boss. The setIs option still needs editing though.

Comment: Are you coming from a C++ or similar background? These three people don't actually have the same boss, you are creating multiple independent copies of Alice.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: You could alternatively use and instead link the Employer to the Employee:

```
setMethod("Bosses","Employee",function(object) object@boss)
setIs("Employee","Person",
      coerce = function(old) old@boss,
      replace =  function(old,new_val){
        old@name<-new_val
        old
      })
setMethod("Bosses","Person", function(object) object@boss)
Bosses(john)
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "Alice"

Slot "age":
[1] 40
```

Perhaps someone has a better answer, here's an alternative:

```
setGeneric("Bosses",function(object) standardGeneric("Bosses"))
setMethod("Bosses","Employee",function(object) object@boss)
my_employees<-list(john,bob,jane)
lapply(my_employees,Bosses) #Maybe implement this in s4?
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "Alice"

Slot "age":
[1] 40


[[2]]
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "Alice"

Slot "age":
[1] 40


[[3]]
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "Alice"

Slot "age":
[1] 40
```